# Why is my character rendering broken in EEVEE but not in Cycle Render?

Tags: 3d, rendering, blender, texture-mapping

I am trying to render using `EEVEE` for a project. I rendered this character in `EEVEE` and my character turned out to be broken. However, it works fine using cycle render.

[cycle render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCsQn.jpg)
[`EEVEE` close up render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbiex.jpg)
[`EEVEE` zoom out render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhXYD.jpg)
[close up of the broken texture(?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJn80.png)

I've turned `EEVEE` Material Opacity Settings To Alpha blend and the render result improved a bit. But it is still broken.
I also realized the broken of the character is worst when I zoom out my camera. And the broken is lesser when it is close up. See the attached images.

Does anyone meet this problem before? What should I do to get rid of the broken material or texture?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that youre using nodes on the texture/material of the character that are not compatible with eevee? I had a similar problem when I tried to render with eevee using some displacement nodes.